# How to fix dnf install on Centos 8

Tags: ansible, centos-8

I need this command to work:

```
$ dnf install postgresql12
```

Now it raises an error:

> No match for argument: postgresql12
>   Error: Unable to find a match: postgresql12

However, if I specify repo, it starts working:

```
$ dnf --repo postgresql install postgresql12
```

But I need the first variant `dnf install postgresql12`, since I'm using Ansible dnf module, which raises the very same error as a raw command:

> - No package postgresql12 available.

So, how can I fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I hesitate to add this as an answer because I'm not sure it's a good way to fix it.. 
But anyway I had the same issue and 'fixed' it by adding `module_hotfixes=true` in /etc/dnf/dnf.conf.

https://dnf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/conf_ref.html tells us:

> module_hotfixes
>
> boolean
>
> Set this to True to disable module RPM filtering and make all RPMs from the repository available. The default is False. This allows user
>   to create a repository with cherry-picked hotfixes that are included
>   in a package set on a modular system.

I'm not sure why this works in this case, I only have dnf on some sandbox servers and never got to the bottom of it.

Comment: Thanks! I will check it. Though it looks like a dirty hack :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the repository, either by editing the .repo file to add `enabled=1` or by running `dnf config-manager --set-enabled postgresql`

Comment: How to check if a repo is enabled or not? The catch is, if I run `yum -v repolist`, I see the repo in the list, so it seems like it is enabled.

Comment: Well, `yum repolist enabled` also shows `postgresql` repository. So, it is definitely enabled, but it still does not work

Comment: I added a screen, which shows this error